# ASP.NET AuthorizeFilter Send to 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working in ASP.NET 5.  I am creating a new filter inherited from AuthorizeFilter.

I am overriding "OnAuthorizationAsync()"  The code looks like this:

```
public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.AuthorizationContext context)
{
   var isSpecialCase = true;
   if (isSpecialCase)
   {
      context.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
      context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
      return Task.FromResult(0);
   }
   //If not special case, lets the base handler do its work
   else
   {
      return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
   }
}
```

This works exactly how I want to except for one issue.  Rather than returning the typical 404 error that I find when navigating to a page that truly does not exist, this simply returns a blank page.

I believe the main problem is that returning a "HttpNotFoundResult" is returning an ActionResult(), not a ViewResult().  I would expect, however, that the action would get converted to the desired view.

Why is it returning a blank page, and how can I instead get it to return the correct 404 error page?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Returning 404 instead of 403 might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "File Not Found");
```

Or try this (mvc 6)

Do not return a task (remove return) just set the response status code to 404:

```
  context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

Depending on your hosting the context sent back will be different. I.e set custom error page for 404 in iis

Also check that you in fact receiving a 404 checking the response in fiddler or browser dev tools.

Comment: I get an unhandled exception error.  I could handle it, but then I would be in the same boat.  Also, I need to avoid using System.Web namespace so that I can stay in dnxcore50.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try updated answer, I had a look at the AuthorizeFilter code and only the context.result is set. So the same can be done for 404s, check that you are intact receiving a 404 on the client, https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ec582d45124550542cbbb10c31da2dbb3568ba19/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Extensions/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs

Comment: Same issue with that one as well.  I am receiving a 404.